# Django logging thread safety between server and commands

Tags: python, django, logging

I want output from my Django server as well as Django management commands to all be written to the same file.  This is easy to set up in the settings.py file, but are there any concerns with thread safety or file locking with a management command (which is run from the command line) trying to write to the same file as the main Django server (running from wsgi)?  Any concerns with this set up running under Windows vs Linux or other operating systems?

In case there are different answers in different versions:
python 3.4
Django 1.11

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Python 3 [Logging Cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes):  "logging to a single file from multiple processes is not supported, because there is no standard way to serialize access to a single file across multiple processes in Python"

Since logging in Django appears to be the default Python logging package I can only assume that it is not meant for access from the main server and commands at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be for all logging to be sent to a queue (e.g. a Redis queue) and then a single process reads the queue and writes records to file. There could be much more to think about here, so this may or may not be appropriate for your needs, but it would eliminate file locking.

Comment: Thanks - that's very similar to what is in the logging cookbook